# Careers not sending email invites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I sent an invite to Careers2.0 to a friend of mine. Couple hours later, he told me he hasn't received the invite. Asked him to check his Spam folders etc - there was no sign of the mail.

To test it out, I sent an invite to another account of mine - an hour's gone by and I'm yet to receive the invite.

Are the hamsters taking a break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're working on some new e-mail infrastructure.  So far, it's been a marked improvement over the previous iteration of e-mail, but there could still be some exceptions that need to be investigated.

Specifically regarding this incident, it appears that there was an issue in the mail sending code which was corrected this morning.  You indicated to me in chat that subsequent tests succeeded for you, so we'll consider this case closed for now, but feel free to poke this question if you notice it misbehaving again.

Comment: Indeed, I did get the invite now. Thanks @Peter, will ping you if something's off

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much for the report.  This was totally my fault and I'm sorry your friend didn't get their invite in a timely manner.

For everyone's information, this led to a careers-wide rewrite of our mail code to make sure we really [fixed this twice](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/customerservice.html) and that this kind of problem (e-mails that we mean to get sent not getting sent) never happens again.  While we were recovering from this (getting all the e-mails sent) we realized we were making almost every mistake when it came to robust email code and I went about fixing it all. Tons of unit/integration tests, 100% queued email, the whole nine.